# Grid sorting based on properties on the view model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, viewmodel

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC4 web application. It uses the entity framework for data access. Many of the pages contain grids. These need to support paging, sorting, filtering and grouping. For performance the grid filtering, sorting, paging etc needs to occur on the database (i.e. the entity framework needs to generate a suitable SQL query). One complication is that the view model to represent the grid rows is built by combining the data from multiple business entities (tables). This could be simply getting the data from an entity a couple of levels down or by calculating it based on the values of related business entities. What approach is recommended to handle this scenario? Does anyone know of a good example on the web? Most have a simple mapping between the view model and business domain model.

Update 28/11 - To further clarify the initial display of the grid and paging works performs well. (See comment below) The problem is how do you handle sorting/ordering (and filtering) when the column that the user clicked on does not map directly to a column on the underlying business table. I am looking for a general solution to achieving this as the system will have approx 100 grids with a number of columns each and trying to handle this on a per column basis will not be maintainable.

Comment: Let me just check I am with you... you want to Map multiple Business Entities to one ViewModel, then you will have an IEnumberable<ViewModelClass> to represent a Grid in the View?

Comment: Yes, a search is performed on the services layer that returns an IQueryable<TopLevelDomainModelClass>. This is done to make it possible to perform further filtering/sorting/paging e.g. The grid. When the results are enumerated they are selected into an ViewModelClass. This class is usually just flattening the business domain classes. But it can have calculated/combined fields. This results in the entity framework generating queries with good performance. I'm looking for advice/examples on handling sorting/filtering on these view model columns that result in a query to the database.

Comment: Ok cool, i will answer shortly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to order a calculated field that isn't pre calculated in the database or do any Database Operation against it, then you are going to have to precalulate the value and store it in the database. I don't know anyway around that.

The only other solution is to move the paging and sorting etc to the web server, I am sure you don't really want to do that as you will have to calculate ALL the values to find what order they go in.

So if you want to achieve what you want - I think you will have to do the following, I would love to hear alternate solutions though:

**Database Level Changes:**

1. Add a Nullable Column for each calculated field you have in your View Model.
2. Write a SQL Script the calculates these values.
3. Set the column to Not Null if necessary

**App Level Changes:**

1. In your Add and Edit Pages you will have to calculate these values and Commit them with the rest of the data

You can now query against these at a Database level and use Queryable as you wanted.